# How can we judge whether an American middle class citizen is better off financially on a comparable salary strata as an Indian middle class citizen?

Tags: inequality, united-states, saving, living-cost

Given two citizens with comparable living standards in two countries, who would have a better life? A better life here is defined by a) how much they could save at the end of a fiscal year and b) quality of life. This question arises because standards of living in countries are different(sometimes vastly), and the amount similar lifestyles cost would be different (based on purchasing power parity)

Some clarifications:

- "Comparable salary strata" means salaries which can afford similar kinds of lifestyles in both countries (adjusting for purchasing power parity)

My ideas:

- The main way is by having some sort of comparison between a quality of life indicator(I don't know if there exists an economic metric for this) and purchasing power parity.
- Looking at a basket of products which both of the citizens would buy and comparing how much is saved after accounting for purchasing power parity. (I am not sure if purchasing power parity already accounts for this, and I might be double counting)

(My question here is also pointing towards what kind of metrics could be used.)